# How can I check new versions of my application without an app store?

Tags: react-native, deployment, download, google-play, updates

I have an application where the .apk can be download from my website, but I don't want to use an application store like Google Play Stroe, my question is, I want the new versions of my application to reach everyone and I don't know very well how to do this.

My application is made in react native and I have looked for a way to do this but I can't find anything, the truth is that I'm a bit lost and if someone could shed some light on the matter, I would really appreciate it.

Extensive information:

I would like that the user can download the highest version of the apk and that it be installed directly from the application itself without the user having to return to my website to download the new version?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the highest version of your app somewhere on your backend, and you need to store the app's current version in itself.

You have to write a function in your app that checks the backend for the highest available app version on every start, and if it's higher than the version stored in the app, then you instruct the user(for example a modal) to download the newest version.

Comment: Thanks, this helps me, but is there a way to download the highest version of the apk and to install it directly from the application itself without the user having to return to my website to download the new version?

Comment: You cant install automatically a new version, it is impossible, however, you can force the users to download the new.
In the backend response, when you check the version, you give the link, and in the app the user can download it by for example clicking on an update button. The rest is on the user, you can't force them directly to install the new app, but you can prevent them from using the current version. For example if the app needs an update, you navigate to the screen the states an update is necessary, and dont let them do anything else.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, you have helped me a lot, I would like to give you a reputation, but I can not because I am new sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for dynamic app updates , without forcing the user to downloading the full sized apk each time there is an update to the app then go for code push, i am using it with my react native android application, it is awesome  makes the work very easy.

[https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/][1]